# Can we retain Data in Vue which comes from an API

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So we have this single post component and below there is other related post list related to this main post, which loads using scroll pagination.
this data is dynamic and coming from an API end.

Now when we click one of these related posts, we get the single view of that post and other related posts of that post comes in the bottom.

So on going back to the prev post is there a way we can just remember all the related posts for that post so that the browser scroll is on that related post item and all the related posts taken previously populates the related post list

And we are using same components for related posts

Comment: You may want to look into [keep-alive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components)